# Использование матриц преобразования плоской фигуры

Tags: python, tkinter

Вопрос конечно простой, но не могу найти инфу на русском.
Как правильно в самом простом виде использовать матрицы для преобразования рисунка?
Например матрицу поворота, которая для плоскости имеет вид 2×2. Надо каждую координату объекта циклом умножить на каждый элемент такой матрицы, или как?

Comment: Вектор координат умножить на матрицу, получить новый вектор.

Comment: Хорошо, а каким образом умножить? У вектора на плоскости две координаты, надо каждую умножить по очереди на каждый элемент матрицы или как?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что вектор координат нужно представить матрицей 2×1 и умножить на матрицу 2×2? Тогда понятно.

Comment: Да, именно так. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно посмотреть как [`turtle.Vec2D.rotate` метод](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0250de48199552cdaed5a4fe44b3f9cdb5325363/Lib/turtle.py#L267-L273) реализован. Его суть сводится к умножению матрицы поворота на сам вектор:

```
x, y = x*c - y*s, y*c + x*s
```

где `с, s = cos(angle), sin(angle)`. Это просто буквально матричное умножение, к примеру если взять `R` матрицу:

```
⎡R₀₀  R₀₁⎤
⎢        ⎥
⎣R₁₀  R₁₁⎦
```

и умножить на `v` вектор:

```
⎡v₀₀⎤
⎢   ⎥
⎣v₁₀⎦
```

то произведение `R⋅v` выглядит как вектор:

```
⎡R₀₀⋅v₀₀ + R₀₁⋅v₁₀⎤
⎢                 ⎥
⎣R₁₀⋅v₀₀ + R₁₁⋅v₁₀⎦
```

Таким образом, чтобы повернуть точку `x1`, `y1` относительно `x0`, `y0` центра на угл `angle`:

```
from turtle import Vec2D

def rotate2D(angle, x0, y0, x1, y1):
    """Rotate (x0, y0) -> (x1, y1) vector by *angle*."""
    x, y = Vec2D(x1-x0, y1-y0).rotate(angle)
    return x + x0, y + y0
```

Пример с вращающимся треугольником:

[image: rotating cyan triangle on white background]

```
import tkinter as tk

def draw2Dpolygon(canvas, points, alpha, origin, *, color='gray'):
    points = [rotate2D(alpha, *[*origin, *p]) for p in points]
    canvas.create_polygon(points, outline=color, fill=color)

def draw_circle(canvas, center, radius, *, color='black'):
    x, y, r = *center, radius
    canvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline=color)

def make_loop():
    width, height = 400, 300
    canvas = tk.Canvas(width=width, height=height, background='white')
    canvas.pack()

    angle = 0
    A = width // 4, height // 4
    B = 3 * width // 4, height // 4
    C = width // 2, 3*height // 4
    origin = width // 2, height // 2

    def loop():
        nonlocal angle
        angle += .025
        canvas.delete('all')  # clear canvas
        draw2Dpolygon(canvas, [A, B, C], angle, origin, color='#0DD')
        draw_circle(canvas, origin, radius=5, color='red')
        root.after(1, loop)
    return loop

root = tk.Tk()
root.after_idle(make_loop())
root.mainloop()
```