# Можно ли как-то повернуть прямоугольник?

Tags: python, tkinter

Прямоугольник на канвасе задается двумя точками, лежащими на концах диагонали,  однако, если применить к ним вращениие, то прямоугольник просто будет сужаться и вытягиваться, но не крутиться, т.е. его стороны всегда параллельны сторонам окна.
Вопрос: можно ли как-нибудь реализовать его вращение, при котором он будет вращаться как цельная фигура?

Comment: Реализовать можно - рассчитывать координаты всех 4-х углов для каждого положения и рисовать полигон из отрезков. Встроенных функций для вращения нет.

Comment: я же вам [явно показал как можно произвольный многоугольник вращать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/819722/23044) (на примере треугольника). Чтобы получить прямоугольник, добавьте четвёртую точку.