# Преобразования задаются матрицами

Tags: python

Дали вот такое задание: "Создать анимированный рисунок, иллюстрирующий преобразования плоской фигуры. Преобразования задаются матрицами." Дословно.
И я не могу понять до конца, что именно оно значит? Как преобразования могут задаваться матрицами? На ум приходит только матрица поворота, но она для точки служит, а не для фигуры. Ну даже если взять её, это только 1 преобразование будет, а в задании множественное число. Какие ещё преобразования, задающиеся матрицами, могут быть? По возможности с пояснениями или примерами.

Comment: "На ум приходит только матрица поворота, но она для точки служит, а не для фигуры." - фигуры состоят из точек.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Использование матриц преобразования плоской фигуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/819722/23044)